# Change color of cupertino scrollbar in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I need to change color of cupertino scrollbar, but I can't do that via normal constructor. Is there any way to make scrollbar white?

```
    CupertinoScrollbar(
              thickness: 5,
              controller: scrollController,
              thicknessWhileDragging: 8,
              //color not exist
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CupertinoScrollBar is hardcoded so on iOS you can't change the color, but you can use `highlightColor` for the ThemeData. The Color will then displayed on Android only.

```
MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        //main color
        primaryColor: const Color(0xffFFC600),
        //main font
        fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium',
        //swatch stretching
        primarySwatch: goldenThemeColor,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,

        splashColor:  const Color(0xffFFC600),

        //color for scrollbar
        highlightColor: Color(0xffffc600)

      ),
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LandingPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LandingPageState();
  }
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
  ScrollController _controller;
  double _offset = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = ScrollController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _controller,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //Scroll bar
          Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: 20.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black12),
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      child: Container(
                      height: 40.0,
                      width: 15.0,
                      margin:
                          EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 5.0, top: _offset),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey, //Change Color here
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3.0))),
                    ),
                      onVerticalDragUpdate: (dragUpdate) {
                        _controller.position.moveTo(dragUpdate.globalPosition.dy * 3.5);

                        setState(() {
                           if(dragUpdate.globalPosition.dy >= 0) {
                             _offset = dragUpdate.globalPosition.dy;
                           }
                          print("View offset ${_controller.offset} scroll-bar offset ${_offset}");
                        });
                      },
                ),
              )
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to change color to web

Comment: @Andryue What do you mean with "change color to web"? Web is not a Color

Comment: I make website in flutter and i need change color to the website not android app

Comment: Okay, that was an Information that you didn't wrote but that is very importend and we missed. Have you tried what I posted?

Comment: I have Updated my Solution. If it is working, please do not forget Accept this answer.